# NHibernate Insert Ignore

Tags: .net, mysql, nhibernate, insert

I need use Insert Ignore for my table, which have Unique index on several fields.
How can i do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe insert ignore is a mysql-specific extension to SQL, which means it's not supported by most DBs.

You will need to fallback on raw SQL on this one, or make use of the exceptions thrown by NHibernate (and the underlying dialect)